# How to get the "risk-score" output in github action when scanning with kubescape?

Tags: security, kubernetes, yaml, github-actions

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the risk-score output from a kubescape scan?
I know that we can use the parameter "-t 25" in the command for github action, but I want to use a warning instead or returning an exit error if the risk-score is above the threshold value.

***Here is a quick overview of what I want to have:***

```
  jobs:
  warning_message:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    #code for getting the risk-score output
    steps:
      - name: check_comparaison_risk-score
        if: ${{ risk_output }} > 25
        run: echo "::warning ::Risk-score is above 25%"
```

You can propose another solution/alternative to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [official Kubescape GitHub actions](https://github.com/kubescape/github-action), and add the`failedThreshold` as shown in the [inputs](https://github.com/kubescape/github-action#inputs) section:

```
name: Kubescape scanning for misconfigurations
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  kubescape:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: kubescape/github-action@main
      with:
        format: sarif
        outputFile: results.sarif
        # # Optional: Specify the Kubescape cloud account ID
        # account: ${{secrets.KUBESCAPE_ACCOUNT}}
        # Fail when the risk-score is higher than X 
        failedThreshold: 25

    - name: Upload Kubescape scan results to Github Code Scanning
      uses: github/codeql-action/upload-sarif@v2
      with:
        sarif_file: results.sarif
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the initial problem, but indeed, I should have used the official Kubescape Github actions.

Comment: @APB-s I think you should open an issue in the Kubescape github page for supporting this.
If you take a look at the Kubescape output, you will see that the risk-score is printed to the stdout, so you can parse the output and use that.